# trouble with type casting: element of char array to an integer variable

Tags: c++

Here is my attempt at doing a problem in a book I'm trying to learn programming from. The problem wants you to convert height in feet and inches into just inches, by only using 1 cin command, instead of asking for feet and inches individually.

```
cout << "Enter height in following format F'I\":";
cin >> height;
feet = (int)height[0];
inches = (int)height[2];

cout << "feet/height[0]: " << feet << "/" << height[0] << "\t" << "inches/height[2]: " << inches << "/" << height[2] << endl; //to test what went wrong, didn't help me much

cout << "You are " << feet * 12 + inches << " inches tall";
```

The output is as follows for an input of 6'8"

```
Enter height in following format F'I":6'8"
feet/height[0]: 54/6    inches/height[2]: 56/8
You are 704 inches tall
```

In my first version of this I had feet = height[0] and inches = height[2] without the cast. From my limited understanding of programming and C++ it seems like its getting the ascii number for 6 and 8 so I used an int cast to try and fix it, but it returned the same results.

Comment: All the int cast does to a char is give the numerical representation, not actually convert `'5'` to the number 5. However, 0-9 are guaranteed to be contiguous, so `'5' - '0'` will always give you 5 as a result.

Comment: Think about what you'll do if someone is 5'11"

Answer (score 0):

The numbers entered by the user will have to be converted from ascii to numerical representation.  This is not a typecasting problem but a conversion error.
You can use atoi() to parse the string and interpret it as an integer.  But you will need to do it such that the characters ' and " are detected.

Answer (score -1):

As @bobestm answered, this isn't a casting issue. You need to convert the C-string into an integer. He suggested [atoi()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), but I prefer [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) when using C++:

```
char some_string[100];

cout << "Enter your number: " << endl;
cin >> some_string;

istringstream iss;
iss.str(string(some_string));

int num;

iss >> num;

if (iss.fail())
{
    cout << some_string << " is not a number! " << endl;
}
```

However, `cin` allows formatted input, so you can just let the user input the integer without any conversions:

```
int some_int;

cout << "Enter your number: " << endl;
cin >> some_int;
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to fit your integers into a single ASCII character. You may want to read up more on [C-strings](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html). Although [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is much easier to use in C++, it would still help you to learn how C-strings work.

This should do what you need:

```
string str;
cout << "Enter height in following format F'I\":"

getline(cin, str);

size_t index = str.find("'");

string feet_str = str.substr(0, index);
string inches_str = str.substr(index + 1);

int feet, inches;

istringstream iss;

iss.str(feet_str);
iss >> feet;

iss.clear();

iss.str(inches_str);
iss >> inches;
```

Comment: If the standard library is updated to the new C++11 standard, [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) might be preferred before using string streams.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg true. That would be the better choice if C++11 is an option. Judging by the down vote, some other folks probably agree.